# this.textInput.focus is not a function - React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have FormControl for password input with icon that toggles the mask, so u cant see the characters you are inputting. But whenever I toggle this mask I also want to re-focus the input field.

```
<FormGroup
    className="input-text input-text--password"
    controlId={id}
    validationState={submitFailed && touched && error ? 'error' : validationState}
  >

    <FormControl
      {...input}
      disabled={disabled}
      className="input-text__input"
      autoFocus={autoFocus}
      type={maskEnabled ? 'password' : 'input'}
      onChange={this.handleFormControlChange}
      maxLength={maxLength}
      ref = { ref => this.textInput = ref }
    />
    <div
        className={'input-text__button ' + (maskEnabled ? 'mask-enabled' : 'mask-disabled')}
        onClick={this.handleToggleInputMode}
    />
```

... I use this method to focus:

```
handleToggleInputMode() {
  let newMaskEnabled = !this.state.maskEnabled;
  this.setState({maskEnabled: newMaskEnabled});
  this.textInput.focus();
}
```

But i keep getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.textInput.focus is not a function

So i tried to put it in ComponentDidMount but then the whole componend stopped responding (didnt accept any char I typed in).
What am i missing?

Comment: maybe provide the whole component's code

Comment: relevant: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/9328#issuecomment-298438237 - can get called with `null` - read caveats also here about anon funcs there. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats

Answer (score 5):

Please check working demo

```js
 class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.textInput.focus();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            defaultValue="It will not focus"
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input
            ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
            defaultValue="with focus"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

**Edit**

for FormControl you should use [inputRef](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#exposing-dom-refs-to-parent-components) as per [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html)

```
<FormControl inputRef={ref => { this.input = ref; }} />
```

Comment: I did but it didnt help. I think both syntaxes are equivalent.

Comment: I did, I think the difference is for me to use the formControl which have different support for ref. If you wan to find it, u gotta use findDOMNode. I eventually solved the problem using inputRef instead of ordinary ref

Comment: Good to hear you solve issue, you can add your answer if you want

Comment: `inputRef` did it for me.

Comment: Could you please look into this similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766100/typeerror-fieldrefcurrent-blur-is-not-a-function?

Answer (score 1):

According to the current docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), use:

```
this.textInput.current.focus();
```

So it should reference to the `current` to get the DOM node.

Comment: Could you please look into this similar problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766100/typeerror-fieldrefcurrent-blur-is-not-a-function