# TypeError: _fieldRef$current.blur is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, native-base

I used `useRef` & `ref` for a custom FieldInput component that contains `<Input>` from Native Base.

```
const fieldRef = useRef();
...
    const handleSubmitForm = (
    values: FormValues,
    helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>,
  ) => {
 ....
    fieldRef.current.blur();
    helpers.resetForm();
  };
```

However, I was getting an error on fieldRef.current that `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`. So, I changed it like this:

```
const fieldRef = useRef<any>(null);
```

```
fieldRef.current?.blur();
```

This fixed the inline error but upon submitting the form, I still get this:

```
Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: _fieldRef$current.blur is not a function
```

How can I fix this? Any workaround would help. I just want to remove the warning.

**codesandbox**: https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/jealous-beef-jerky-fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more check to the `if` condition. This should remove the warning.

```
if (fieldRef && fieldRef.current && fieldRef.current.blur)
```